# What prerequisites package is needed for Oracle 11g + 12c on the same OL7 server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-11g, installation

I need to install 3 Oracle homes on the same Oracle Linux 7 server, but it's not clear to me what prerequisites I need to install before proceeding.

What I'm planning to set up, is a two-standalone-instance (11.2 + 12.2) server and an Oracle Grid infrastructure for taking advantage of the benefits of the Oracle Restart.

As a prerequisite, on OL7 we need to run:

- yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall -y   (in case on Oracle 11.2)
- yum install oracle-database-server-12cR2-preinstall -y   (in case on Oracle 12.2)

Considering I'm planning to install the following Oracle homes

- 12.2 Grid infrastructure
- 12.2 Database
- 11.2 Database

should I run both the aforementioned yum commands, or only 12cR2 prerequisite is actually required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `oracle-database-server-12cR2-preinstall` is that it does not install `gcc`. For a base release, it is fine, but upon installing a PSU/RU, opatch fails because of that.

```
[root@o61 ~]# yum deplist oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-14.el6.x86_64 | grep dependency | grep gcc
  dependency: gcc-c++
  dependency: gcc
  dependency: libgcc
[root@o61 ~]#

[root@o71 ~]# yum deplist oracle-database-server-12cR2-preinstall.x86_64 | grep dependency | grep gcc
  dependency: libgcc
[root@o71 ~]#
```

It is not needed to install both packages. I would just do this (as I usually do):

```
yum install oracle-database-server-12cR2-preinstall gcc gcc-c++ -y
```

Comment: Got it, I take you reply as satisfactory, but honestly I don't remember to have never explicitely installed neither gcc nor gcc-c++ before applying PSUs via OPatch.